# stat() and ampersand operator

Tags: php

I've been studying WordPress source code that operates on the filesystem, when I hit these few lines and I'm really not quite sure what they do?

```
$stat = stat( dirname( $new_file ));
$perms = $stat['mode'] & 0000666;
@ chmod( $new_file, $perms );
```

Comment: +1 for a valid question considering you don't see many utilizing bitwise operators in PHP. For more information on bitwise operators, please take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code uses bitwise operations to ensure that a file's permissions are no higher than 666.
To break it down:

```
// Retrieves the file details, including current file permissions.
$stat = stat( dirname( $new_file )); 

// The file permissions are and-ed with the octal value 0000666 to make
// sure that the file mode is no higher than 666. In other words, it locks
// the file down, making sure that current permissions are no higher than 666,
// or owner, group and world read/write.
$perms = $stat['mode'] & 0000666; 

// Finally, the new permissions are set back on the file
@chmod( $new_file, $perms );
```

Comment: "to ensure that a particular file attribute is set" -- or "not set" in this case: everything that is not contained in 666 (rw-rw-rw-) is removed -- in practice this means execute bits.

Comment: Much appreciated Jon! But I'm guessing if the file perms were already, for example, 600, then $perms would remain 600?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic - Correct. The code only removes permissions, it does not add them.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the permission to allow writing in a directory.. I think. Check out [stat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) and [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).

Comment: Yes, but why fetch the chmod info in the first place, and why `&`  it with 666? I don't get it, either. Let's see whether anybody comes along who can solve this riddle.

Comment: It drops the extra bits and retains only the `rwxrwxrwx` part, whichever bits of it are set.

Answer (score 0):

`0666` is the octal notation for the unix `rwxrwxrwx` permissions, so I'm assuming the `$stat['mode']` returns the permissions of the folder. Then they get bitwise AND'ed with the `0666` mask to check if you have *at least* read/write/execute permissions for self, group and others.

Comment: `x` permissions are bit 0 (1 in hex/octal), these are not set. So 666 means rw-rw-rw-. Also, the AND operator only keeps bits that are 1 in *both* operands, so the code actually *removes* all permissions that are *not* read/write.